# What does the letter V in Thomas Pynchon's book symbolize?

Tags: symbolism, thomas-pynchon, v

Obviously, V. is a character in the book, known only by her initial. That initial is also the title of the book, which actually includes the period.

But I assume this title/name symbolizes something else too?

[Wikipedia's article "V."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V.) only mentions one other meaning, the convergence of the two main plotlines, which seems a little tenuous. Other than that, this book is pretty hard to google.

Comment: As an unrelated comment, I was just reading _V for Vendetta_ the week before, and V reads this exact book. I thought I should check it out, but never got to do it. And now, while typing a question, your post came up in suggested duplicates :)

Comment: Nice question! (["Pynchon’s V is an escaped signifier running amok through his narrative."](http://cultural-discourse.com/on-thomas-pynchons-first-novel-v/) ;)

Comment: Isn't it also a reference to the V-Rockets of the nazis? The V2 to be precise?

Comment: @Swizzler Is it? That's news to me. Does it appear in this book at all? (It was written before _Gravity's Rainbow_.)

Comment: @tobiasvl my bad, I mixed up the timeline. This one is a nice interpretation: https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-understand-the-meaning-of-the-letter-v-in-Thomas-Pynchons-novel-V